# How can I avoid a cross aggregate transaction?

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, transaction, aggregate

Consider this simplified example: In an online ticket sale website, tickets have variable prices that change over time.

User searches for **tickets**. Once he finds a ticket he wants, clicks "Buy" and then a **quote** is issued. Quotes are persisted and they have they own locator that is sent by email. The quote page opens, showing the breakdown of what he is going to pay, and a button to pay. At this point, the ticket is still available for others. If the user clicks on "Pay now", a payment process starts and a **Purchase Order** is issued with his details.

When a purchase order is paid, the quote status must be set as "Accepted" and reference the purchase order; the ticket status is set as "Sold".

As per requirements, this must happen in an atomic fashion, meaning that it is not acceptable to have a paid purchase order referencing a non accepted quote, or a non sold ticket at any given time. Essentially, eventual consistency is not allowed.

There are two big aggregates, `Quote` and `PurchaseOrder`. The first manages the breakdown calculation, taxes, etc... The second manages payment details for a quote, payment event raising, etc... The problem I have is that right now it seems I have to use a transaction across ticket, quote and purchase order when the last is paid.

How may I model this honoring the "Transactions should not cross aggregate boundaries" rule?

Comment: I'm going to be shallow and drop some links for you:
https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/05/25/ddd-the-aggregate/ 
and https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838

Comment: If they need to be in the same transaction boundary, then Quote and Purchase Order are not likely to be aggregates. They are artifacts (perhaps entities) managed by the aggregate. They actually sound like documents (without behavior) which are produced in the process of executing aggregate behaviors.

Comment: Would not that lead to the "too big aggregate" issue? I thought about a ReservationAggregate, however a quote is not a reservation.

Answer (score 6):

You need a process manager/saga that do exactly what you need without using transaction that spawn multiple aggregates.

Basically that Saga would `reserve` the ticket right before the payment begins and would `markTicketAsSold` after the payment is successful or `releaseTheReservation` after the payment is failed.

This process and the invariant that a `reserved` or `sold` ticket cannot be `reserved` again would ensure that the system as a hole is in the correct state at all times.

> As per requirements, this must happen in an atomic fashion, meaning that it is not acceptable to have a paid purchase order referencing a non accepted quote, or a non sold ticket at any given time. Essentially, eventual consistency is not allowed.

This does not seem to be a valid invariant. The invariant should be "a sold ticket cannot be sold again". **Carefully defining the business invariants** will help you in designing the aggregate boundaries and correctly modeling the long running processes.

Comment: But when you commit the saga, still have to modify ticket, quote and purchase order state at the same time. Same problem again.

Comment: @NullOrEmpty I don't understand what you mean by commiting the Saga

Comment: @NullOrEmpty I think my `commit` term from the answer is not ok. I will edit it

Comment: @NullOrEmpty You must carefully define the invariants. In your case "it is not acceptable to have a paid purchase order referencing a non accepted quote" does not seem to be a valid invariant but "a sold ticket can not be sold again" is

Comment: Well it is a requirement that in the purchase order page, where purchase order, quote and ticket data are shown, states are consistent at any given time.

Comment: @NullOrEmpty There is a delay between the payment is done and ticket is marked as sold and the quote is accepted but, after the payment is done, the ticket will be marked as sold and the quote accepted for sure; in this case you should fake it in the UI: if the ticket is sold for the current quote then show the quote as accepted, not matter what the quote readmodel says. Anyway, why do you need the quote status?

Comment: "There is a delay between the payment is done and ticket is marked as sold" -- what happens if during this delay 3 more people manage to pay for this same ticket? As per the requirements a ticket is available to other people until marked as sold.

Comment: @Nik a `reserved` ticket cannot be payed again

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu, thank you for the response. Rereading your answer more carefully, I now see how the "saga" approach can work. I'd be grateful, if you can answer one more question. It seems fair to say, the "saga" approach is much more complicated than doing a transaction across the aggregates. And it also doesn't seem likely OP will ever want to scale out ticket selling in such a way that the Quote and PurchaseOrder aggregates will reside in different db-s/on different machines. Isn't the "Transactions should not cross aggregate boundaries" rule too rigid? What's your opinion on this?

Comment: @Nik No, it's not too rigid. If you need to break it then the Aggregate's design is wrong. It's like a test applied to one's architecture. If a Saga/Process manager would suffice then the Aggregates' boundaries are good.